# How to import/export syntax coloring scheme

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Is it possible to export my color scheme, so I can import back and forth on other computers and Anaconda envs? I can't seem to find a practical way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry, Spyder doesn't have this functionality at the moment (February 2020).

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I really thought this would be the case. Something for the future, perhaps? ;-)

Comment: Yep, we'll try to add it for Spyder 4.

Comment: Was this added in Spyder 4?

Comment: No, it was not added, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It is not officially supported feature.
But take a look at [this](https://github.com/joonro/Spyder-Color-Themes).
You can modify ~/.spyder-py3/spyder.ini and ColorSchemeName.ini and save them.

Comment: Head up that in Spyder4, this file is now a level down in ~/.spyder-py3/config/spyder.ini. All the old methods still work for now, but make sure you're using the active spyder.ini! Spyder3 upgrades will still have the old, non-functional .ini hanging around in the old place.